# How to create a new array based on number provided by make the number segregate in a range in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, arrays

I want to create an array that contains the sum of a number in a given range below is the array that I am using

```js
const data = [{
    a: 0,
    b: 0.75,
    c: 0,
    d: 0
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 0.88,
    c: 0,
    d: 0
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 0.38,
    c: 0,
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 3,
    b: 0.7,
    c: 1,
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 4,
    b: 0.93,
    c: 1,
    d: 0
  }
];
```

In the above array, I want my output to look like something which is below

```js
const output = [{
    labelOfB = "0.3 - 0.4",
    CountOfA = 1,
    sumOfC = 1,
    sumOfD = 1
  },
  {
    labelOfB = "0.7 - 0.8",
    CountOfA = 2,
    sumOfC = 1,
    sumOfD = 1
  },
  {
    labelOfB = "0.8 - 0.9",
    CountOfA = 1,
    sumOfC = 0,
    sumOfD = 0
  },
  {
    labelOfB = "0.9 - 1",
    CountOfA = 1,
    sumOfC = 0,
    sumOfD = 0
  }
]
```

So here in the output what we are basically doing is we have a number provided by the user which will always be between 0 to 1 for 0.1, 0.05, or 0.2 so on, with this number we want to create a range

let's say the number is 0.1 so the range will be 0, 0.1, 0.2, up to 1

so with this range, I want my output to fall in this range only and it should never exceed than 1, so if we have a between 0.3 to 0.4 the output will be

```js
{
  labelOfB = "0.3 - 0.4", // range 
    CountOfA = 1, // no of A's in these range
    sumOfC = 1, // sum of C in these range
    sumOfD = 1 // sum of D in this range
}
```

I tried to do these from my end but I suck at for loop

```js
const data = [{
    a: 0,
    b: 0.75,
    c: 0,
    d: 0,
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 0.88,
    c: 0,
    d: 0,
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 0.38,
    c: 0,
    d: 1,
  },
  {
    a: 3,
    b: 0.7,
    c: 1,
    d: 1,
  },
  {
    a: 4,
    b: 0.93,
    c: 1,
    d: 0,
  },
  {
    a: 5,
    b: 0.02,
    c: 1,
    d: 1,
  },
  {
    a: 6,
    b: 0.16,
    c: 0,
    d: 1,
  },
  {
    a: 7,
    b: 0.78,
    c: 1,
    d: 0,
  },
];
const bin = 0.1; // this is the number by which will create range

let dataSet = {};
let CountOfa = 0;
let sumOfC = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 1; j += 0.1) {
    if (j <= data[i].b && data[i].b <= bin + j) {
      CountOfa += 1;
      sumOfC = sumOfC + data[i].c;
      dataSet = {
        CountOfA: CountOfa,
        labelOfB: `${j.toFixed(1)}-${(j + bin).toFixed(1)}`,
        sumOfC: sumOfC,
      };
    }
  }
}

console.log(dataSet);
```

Comment: where do you get the ranges from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const bin = 0.1

const elaborate = (data, bin) => 
Array.from({length:Math.ceil(1 / bin)}, (_, i) => Number((bin * i).toFixed(3)))
.map(start => {
  const inRange = data.filter(({b}) => b >= start && b < start + bin)
  return {
  "CountOfA": inRange.length,
  "labelOfB": `${start.toFixed(2)}-${(start + bin).toFixed(2)}`,
  "sumOfC": inRange.reduce((res, el) => res + el.c, 0),
  "sumOfD": inRange.reduce((res, el) => res + el.d, 0),
}}).filter(d => d.CountOfA > 0)




const data = [{
    a: 0,
    b: 0.75,
    c: 0,
    d: 0
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 0.88,
    c: 0,
    d: 0
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 0.38,
    c: 0,
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 3,
    b: 0.7,
    c: 1,
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 4,
    b: 0.93,
    c: 1,
    d: 0
  }
];

console.log(elaborate(data, bin))
console.log(elaborate(data, 0.05))
console.log(elaborate(data, 0.2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and the solution, I had a query right now we are segregating the value as 0.10-0.20, 0.20-0-30 how can just see the value like 0.10-0.20, 0.21-0.30 because I want the only up to to the bin

Answer (score 0):

You could get the slot by using integer values and get the objects from a hash table.

```js
const
    data = [{ a: 0, b: 0.75, c: 0, d: 0 }, { a: 1, b: 0.88, c: 0, d: 0 }, { a: 2, b: 0.38, c: 0, d: 1 }, { a: 3, b: 0.7, c: 1, d: 1 }, { a: 4, b: 0.93, c: 1, d: 0 }, { a: 5, b: 0.02, c: 1, d: 1 }, { a: 6, b: 0.16, c: 0, d: 1 }, { a: 7, b: 0.78, c: 1, d: 0 }],
    bin = 0.1, // this is the number by which will create range
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { b, c, d }) => {
        const slot = Math.floor(b / bin);
        r[slot] ??= { countOfA: 0, labelOfB: [slot * bin, (slot + 1) * bin].map(v => v.toFixed(1)).join('-'), sumOfC: 0, sumOfD: 0 };
        r[slot].countOfA++;
        r[slot].sumOfC += c;
        r[slot].sumOfD += d;
        return r;
    }, {}));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```